# Mysql returns only the first result

Tags: mysql, cakephp, cakephp-1.2

I have this query for a search form:

```
// General Query
$conditions = array(
    'editore LIKE' => "%$e%",
    'titolo LIKE' => "%$t%"
);
```

Now, if the user chooses fill some field (eg author, year, etc), I have:

```
if (isset($menu)&&$menu!='')
    $conditions[]=array('classe LIKE' => "%$menu%");
```

Or:

```
if ($anno&&$anno2)
    $conditions[] = array('anno BETWEEN ? AND ?' => array($anno,$anno2));
```

If the user chooses some tags for the book, I have:

```
$query_t = $CdBibliotem->query("SELECT codiceBiblio FROM cd_bibliotem WHERE codiceTematica IN (".implode(',', $fields).")");        
$query_t = Set::classicExtract($query_t,'{n}.cd_bibliotem.codiceBiblio'); 
$tot=implode(',', $query_t);
$conditions[]=array('codiceBiblio IN (?)'=> "$tot");
```

This should work, but instead I don't know why, *it gives me only the first record*.
This is an example of debug a final query, where the user selects only 1 tag, and leaves the others fields empty:

```
Array (
[editore LIKE] => %%
[titolo LIKE] => %%
[0] => Array
    (
        [autori LIKE] => %%
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [codiceBiblio IN (?)] => 118729,118656,118645,118554,118534,118533,118532,118531,118530,118529,118528,118527,118526,118121,117632,117515,117040,116562,115851,115787,114613,114612,113545,113385,113142
    ) )
```

In this case, it gives me all the details of the first book (with id=118729), while it should gives me the details of all that books.

Comment: Could you post the query you've got just before it's executed ? It would help separate a potential php issue with a potemtial SQL issue.

Comment: @SamuelEUSTACHI The query before it is executed, it should be the one I written at the end of the question. When the query is executed, it gives me the book with all the details.

Comment: SOLVED HERE: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112779/pass-a-string-in-query-without-using-quotes

Comment: Ok this is solved, but there is no pure SQL query in your question. And I was right to ask for it, as it happens that you had a php error, not an SQL one. Generally speaking, it is better to try to narrow a problem, in order to solve it esily. That's why it 's nice to see what is actually in the query ("echo" it, for instance, if you use PHP) and run the query in the SQL client (say, PhpMyAdmin) to see if the problem comes from here