# Pass a string in query without using quotes ''

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-1.2

I have this code for the query:

```
$conditions[]=array('codiceBiblio IN (?)'=> $tot);
```

Where $tot is a string (eg: 2345,5657,4565,5678). 
In this case, the query will be:

```
SELECT [...] WHERE codiceBiblio IN ('2345,5657,4565,5678')
```

But it will returns just the first record. 
 
So it sould be:

```
SELECT [...] WHERE codiceBiblio IN (2345,5657,4565,5678)
```

How can I do it?

**How the query is built** 
I have this code for a query:

```
// General Query
$conditions = array(
    'editore LIKE' => "%$e%",
    'titolo LIKE' => "%$t%"
);
```

And I fill up $conditions with user's choices, for example:

```
if ($anno&&$anno2)
    $conditions[] = array('anno BETWEEN ? AND ?' => array($anno,$anno2));

if (isset($menu)&&$menu!='')
    $conditions[]=array('classe LIKE' => "%$menu%");
```

Comment: We would need more information on how the query is being build before we can answer that question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just use an array and omit the `IN()` clause. The manual ([Complex Find Conditions](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#complex-find-conditions)) provides this example:

```
array('Company.status' => array('inactive', 'suspended'))
```

... which produces the following SQL:

```
`Company`.`status` IN ('inactive', 'suspended')
```

If `$tot` is a string like `2345,5657,4565,5678` you'll need to [explode()](http://php.net/explode) it first.

**Disclaimer:** This works in Cake 2, not sure about 1.2.

Comment: Tried, but not working, the sql generated is codiceBiblio = ('118956,118746,118456')

Comment: @Ettore - Have you created an array first? I have the impression that if Cake/1 did not support this it would either ignore it or trigger an error, but not combine all array items into a string.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario this also should work in CakePHP 1.2, have used it many times over the years. The full example will be something like `$conditions[] = array('codiceBiblio' => $tot);` but as you mentioned, `$tot` *should be converted to an array* if it contains multiple values. This method is the preferred way of performing this kind of queries in CakePHP and CakePHP will handle escaping/sanitising the values. **unlike the accepted answer**

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario I created an array, and now your code it's working, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Álvaro G. Vicario's suggestion is the correct one, but you can also do this:

```
$conditions[]=array('codiceBiblio IN (' . $tot . ')');
```

Comment: Álvaro G. Vicario's answer is better than mine :-) Consider giving him the right answer tick.

Comment: Although this will probably work, CakePHP will probably *not* escape/sanitise values in $tot, which will make your application vulnerable for SQL injection. Not 100% sure with Cake 1.2, but be sure to test it, or pick Alvaros answer